# Button Text Not Changing with ViewModel Changes

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm trying to change the text of a button based on user interaction. The text is bound to a boolean variable in the view model and is supposed to observe changes in that variable. When the variable changes, the text is supposed to switch. But it's not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="userDataViewModel"
            type="com.mysite.myapp.viewModels.UserDataViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/change_group_location_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.GroupLocationFragment">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/select_location_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:text='@{userDataViewModel.userData.groupChanged ? "changed" : "not changed"}'/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Here is the part of the fragment where I bind the view model:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_group_location, container, false)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

    userDataViewModel = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders
            .of(this, UserDataViewModelFactory(prefs, userDataFetcherService))
            .get(UserDataViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")

    userDataViewModel
        .getUserData()
        .observe(this, Observer {
            binding.userDataViewModel = userDataViewModel
        })

    return binding.root
}
```

I can see that the boolean variable in the view model toggles to 'true', but the button text still says 'not changed'. I just don't see what I am overlooking.

EDIT
Adding in the `ViewModel` class in case the issue is there.

```
class UserDataViewModel(private val prefs: SharedPreferences): ViewModel() {

    val userData: MutableLiveData<UserData> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<UserData>().also {
            val userDataString = prefs.getString(UserData.USER_DATA_SHARED_PREFERENCE_KEY, "")
            it.value = Gson().fromJson(userDataString, UserData::class.java)
        }
    }

    fun getUserData(): LiveData<UserData> {
        return userData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with a button text which you set.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/change_group_location_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.GroupLocationFragment">


    <Button
            android:id="@+id/select_location_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:text='@{userDataViewModel.userData.groupChanged ? `changed` : `not changed`}'/>
```

change it with back quote (`) sign.

Comment: Thanks, but If this were the issue, the app wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string from string.xml also like below

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/select_location_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="@{userDataViewModel.userData.groupChanged ? @string/txt_changed : @string/txt_not/-changed}"
```

Comment: Thanks. I could do that (and I will ultimately), but that isn't the question that I asked for help with.